# wordpress include a second mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, themes

I have a website with some pages, now to add other pages I've installed wordpress  in a subdirectory.

I've created a CHILD THEME for wordpress. In the header.php of my child theme I've included the home.css and the header markup of my main website. All ok!

Because my **main website** already has a connection to a mysql db (not the wp one), i was thinking to add a this mysql connection in the header.php of my child theme too.

So I've added this code as first thing on the header.php of my child theme:

```
function example( $value ) {
global $con;
return mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $value ) );
}

$con = mysqli_connect( HOST, USER, PASS, DB ) or die( 'Error' );

$test = example( 'my string' );
```

While the exact same code work on my main website, in wordpress i get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/user/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/afs/header.php on line 11
```

PS: I think the problem is in the **global $con**, because if I pass **$con as function argument** everything works.

It's possibile to add a second mysql connection in my wordpress child theme unsing **global $con** or should I change all my php functions? I'm curious to understand why this happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to use several db's in WordPress. Easiest I believe is to use a new instance of the WordPress db class and let it take care of referencing the correct connection.

```
$my_second_db = new wpdb( $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_host );
```

You can make it a global of course and then just use the WordPress db functions on your separata database.

```
$my_second_db->query( $my_second_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = %d", $id), ARRAY_A );
```

Or in your case:

```
$my_second_db->escape( $value );
```

But your code would also work just that you have to declare $con as a global before assigning it the db resource. However you won't be able to use all the neat WordPress functions which seems a waste when you've just spent so much juice loading them. Either way this should work:

```
function example( $value ) {
global $con;
return mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, trim( $value ) );
}

global $con;
$con = mysqli_connect( HOST, USER, PASS, DB ) or die( 'Error' );

$test = example( 'my string' );
```

Comment: thanks, for you its a bad practice to set the $con as global?

Comment: No not at all, it's just that when working with the WordPress framework I would personally choose to use their database class since it comes with a heap of nifty features.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb